# Webpack-How to import resource with '!' char

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, webpack-5

i have a lot of image under `img`

such as

`img/xxx!.png`

`img/!$jd.png`

`img/!_$X_9.png`

...

when i try import it,it will fail

```
[webpack-dev-server] WARNING in ./src/raw/img/ sync ^\.\/.*$ ./characters/!$0_1x3_001.png
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './characters/' in 'B:\rpg\test\src\raw\img' index.js:489:22

[webpack-dev-server] WARNING in ./src/raw/img/ sync ^\.\/.*$ ./characters/!$0_1x3_002.png
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './characters/' in 'B:\rpg\test\src\raw\img'
```

code:

```js
function importModule(modulesFiles: __WebpackModuleApi.RequireContext) {
    const all: { [k: string]: any } = {}
    for (const v of modulesFiles.keys()) {
        const value = modulesFiles(v)
        all[v] = value
    }
    return all;
}

const res = importModule('./img')
console.log(res)
//result: ['./xxx.png': 'http://localhost:8080/hash.png', ....]
```

`webpack.config.ts`

```js
const config: Configuration & DevConfig = {
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    devServer: {
        open: true,
        host: 'localhost',
    },
    // devtool: false,
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/index.html',
        })

    ],
    stats: {
        warnings: false
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(ts|tsx|mts)$/i,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: ['/node_modules/'],
            },
            {
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/img'),
                type: 'asset/resource',
            }

            // Add your rules for custom modules here
            // Learn more about loaders from https://webpack.js.org/loaders/
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.jsx', '.js', '.mts', '.mjs', '...']
    },
};
```

and if filename without '!' ,its ok

i cant rename '!' because it was generate by a program.

how to resove it?